# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user to database) when having permissions

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to connect my django project to its MySQL db in an Amazon EC2 instance, but I keep getting the error in the title. What's weird is that I granted all the privileges to the user, but I still keep getting the error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'chile_analyst'@'%' to database 'lms_chile_integration_local'")`

I triple-checked the usernames and passwords coming from the environment file and they are OK.

I also checked the grants for the user:

`mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'chile_analyst'@'%';`

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for chile_analyst@%                                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'chile_analyst'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION                             |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `lms_chile_integration_local`.* TO 'chile_analyst'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can connect to the databse using: `mysql -u chile_analyst -p`, but Django seems to be throwing this error when trying to migrate.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you flush your user privileges, error comes from MySQL

Comment: Yep. I did flush them

Comment: I was getting this same situation, but I went through a UX interface, which automatically lower-cased all DB names. I had just copied a string over without realizing it. Once I lower-cased the `NAME` field, I was all good.

It might be worth just checking to make sure your DB name has the right case in both mysql and in your app.